# MenuInflater like style menu for the iphone development?

Tags: iphone, menu

I am trying to convert an android application to an iphone application and I really like the MenuInflater of the Android which displays a transparent menu over half of the screen.

Is there any type of menu on the iphone that is similar to what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone is totally different than android in-terms of UI.
If you want menu in iPhone,i would say consider `UIActionSheet`..Its pretty..